# angular's ng-submit() directive does not submit while pressing enter on one of text fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've constructed a simple form using angular.
I want that once the user enter some value and then press enter - the ng-click function (in this case updateMsg({name: name,room: room})) will be run.

However, this code does not work like that.. the function run only after pressing the button (not like I want - enter keyboard value, then enter..)

Code is below...

help please?

Thanks

```
<body>
    <div class="Member">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <form name="myForm" ng-submit="updateMsg({name: name,room: room})">
            Please enter your details:
            <br>
            Name: <input name="name" ng-model="name" autocomplete="off">
            <br>
            Room: <input name="room" ng-model="room" autocomplete="off">
            <br>
            <button type="button" ng-click="updateMsg({name: name,room: room})">

            Enter
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ng-click` and `ng-submit` directives together. Add `type="submit"` to your button like this:

```
<button type="submit">Enter</button>
```

and keep only `ng-submit`:

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="updateMsg({name: name,room: room})">
        Please enter your details:
        <br> Name:
        <input name="name" ng-model="name" autocomplete="off">
        <br> Room:
        <input name="room" ng-model="room" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Enter</button>
    </form>
```

Also there is no point in doing `ng-submit="updateMsg({name: name,room: room})"` to pass your updated data like that. Since you are using `ng-model` you are ready to go. You can declare your scope vars initially in the controller and when the form gets submitted you can use them right away. Because of dual-binding your vars will be already updated:

```
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MemberController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.room = '';
    $scope.updateMsg = function() {
        // use updated $scope.name in here
        // use updated $scope.room too
    }
}]);
```

A small [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nxopp5xe9YHPd5m2j5wM?p=preview) to help you some more.

Comment: thanks.. regarding your second advice - I need to pass an **Object** to the  updateMsg() method, which contains two fileds {name: "my name", room: "my room"}. *this method expects* an *object* like that and *not 2 parameters*...

Comment: Ok i see. It seemed somewhat redundant to me since you already have their values so you can create that object in your controller. Of course there are too many ways to do things in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

I think the button should have `type=submit` instead.

```
<button type="submit">
```

instead of

```
<button type="button" ng-click="updateMsg({name: name,room: room})">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling a `event.preventDefault()` method so the form doesn't submit by default? Maybe share the code where you're creating the `updateMsg({name: name,room: room})`.